# when baking vegan lemon drizzle cake, should the soya milk be sweetened or unsweetened, fresh or longlife?

Tags: substitutions

I'm making vegan lemon drizzle cake for a friend and not being vegan myself, I am unfamiliar with some of the ingredients!  Should I use swettened or unsweetened soya milk? If I used sweetened I thought I may be able to lower the amount of sugar that the recipe calls for but not sure of the ratios I will have to have a few practise goes! Also, does it matter if the soya milk is fresh or longlife when making vegan cakes please?

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem w/ the long-life stuff.  (the 'fresh' stuff is likely also long-life, but people think of it more like milk when they see it in the coolers).   I actually prefer the unchilled stuff, as it's available in smaller containers so less likely to go off if I don't use it all up in time.

Sweetened will be closer to the sweetness of cow's milk, which might make substitutions easier if you're converting a recipe yourself.  If you're working from a recipe that calls for soy milk, just go with your own preference.

Comment: Also, you can taste whichever soy milk you choose in the end. If it seems sweeter than regular milk to you, maybe reduce the sugar by a bit, but probably it won't be enough to make a difference in a lemony cake.

Comment: If the recipe intends for you to curdle the soymilk (does it say eg to add lemon juice or vinegar straight to it?), make sure it is soymilk and not rice/almond/... milk you are using, these can behave differently with acids...